# Possible issue with Mac OSX update 10.5.7 and swingUI

Tags: java, macos

We just updated to Mac OSX 10.5.7 and now anytime I bring up any of my SwingUI based dialogs our application crashes.  Literally everything was working fine I just made some good progress on the project and decided to take a break and install the update, I come back boot up the application and discover anytime a swingUI based element comes up, the application crashes.  Does this seem like a plausible cause of my problem or is it just some crazy coincidence?

Comment: Which sort of exception are you getting and Which version of Java are you running?

Comment: I am using java version 1.5.0_19, the exception is a malloc error:  Non-aligned pointer being freed

Comment: Freaky, that looks like a JNI error. Anyway, you can probably downgrade to an earlier JVM, or try a later one. Multiple JVM's can happily coexist on your machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need a newer version of the quaqua JNI libraries linked against 10.5.7?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried updating the VM on your Mac?  A new update came out recently:

> Java for Mac OS X 10.5 Update 4 delivers improved reliability, security, and compatibility for Java SE 6, J2SE 5.0 and J2SE 1.4.2 on Mac OS X 10.5.7 and later. This release updates Java SE 6 to version 1.6.0_13, J2SE 5.0 to version 1.5.0_19, and J2SE 1.4.2 to 1.4.2_21.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the stack trace for hints. I hope you are using an IDE like eclipse or xcode. you can post the stack trace. I think that's more helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately the project was written without an IDE and is compiled using a build.xml file with a call to ant.

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of Swing UI apps and they don't crash under `10.5.7`. What Java version are you using? I tested with `1.6.0_13`, which is the newest version. I compiled this program and it runs just fine:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "x", "z", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    System.exit(0);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's totally possible. If the Java version was updated (which I think it was, though my 10.5.7 just asked me to update the JVM recently, weeks after I updated the OS)... Java updates have traditionally broken some Swing Apps.

If you do a java -version and your version is any of these

```
1.6.0_13
1.5.0_19
1.4.2_21
```

you can be sure that it came with the 10.5.7 update, since these are 10.5.7 and later only.

Run the java command from a command line (to see the stack trace), which will no doubt reveal the problem. If you are the developer, it should be easy to figure out which of your assumptions about how Swing works was wrong.

On the other hand, let's be scientific: it could be a coincidence :)

Answer (score 0):

Apple reverted the java 5 rendering engine to quartz for some reason. You can use java 6 or try setting apple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz to false (on the command line or in Info.plist, whatever that is).

edit: a more verbose discussion on Apple's java-dev list: http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2009/Jun/msg00306.html

Comment: Thank you very much for this link.  Unfortunately it seems that there is no easy way to revert the java version.  According to the Apple tech support rep you need to do an archive and install to a pre updated version and then choose not to install the java update when it comes up.  Correct me if this is wrong I am new to macs.  Also, I don't know what exactly info.plist is but it seems that the add new item is ghosted and I do not see anywhere in there to change the java rendering engine.  Thanks for your help and sorry for the newbie questions.

Comment: I'm just relaying what I heard but yes that's basically correct. However, you can change the active jvm through the Java Preferences, see also http://developer.apple.com/java/faq/#multiple , and you can set that option I mentioned as usual java -Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=false [...]